# Как собрать (скомпилировать )проект на nw.js в windows7

Tags: javascript, html5, cmd, windows-7, nwjs

Как скомпилировать или (собрать) nw.js в Windows 7 Pack 1
Нашёл скрипт .bat файла но он не работает,он приведен ниже и все файлы "проекта".

файл.bat:

```
 C:\Users\lint\Documents\nwjs\nwjs-v0.25.2-win-x64\nw.exe "C:\Users\lint\Documents\nwjs"
```

файл.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

файл package.json

```
{
"main":"index.html",
"name":"Text",
"description": "Test",
"version":"0.0.1",
"keywords":["test","test"],
"window":{
"title":"test",
"icon":"icon.png",
"toolbar":false,
"frame":true,
"width":700,
"height":400,
"position":"center",
"min_width":400,
"min_height":200,
"max_width":800,
"max_height":600
},
"author":"Anton",
"license":"MIT",
"dependencies":{
"moment":"latest",
"handlebars":"^2.0.0"
}

}
```

файлы render.js и style.css пусты

Comment: Собрать [проект](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/) или все же собрать сам [фреймворк](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Building%20NW.js/)?

Comment: Спасибо, подправил, собрать проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ в комментарии:
Собрать [проект](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/) или все же собрать сам [фреймворк](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Building%20NW.js/)